# Protecting love for Hashem

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, shema, chinuch-education

The Sh'ma opens with the commandment to love the L_rd your G_d with all your heart, all your soul and all your resources.

To help protect the sanctity of Shabbat, there are laws which build a fence around the observance, keeping sanctity of Shabbat a step away from desecration; are there similar guidelines or laws in halacha to help protect the observance of the commandment to love Hashem?

I can think of many instructions which *contribute* to one's loving Hashem - for example, the many blessings of thanks help one keep in touch with one's gratitude for the pleasures of existence. But what is there that is expressly concerned with *avoiding damage* to your own, or someone else's love for Hashem?

Are there guidelines for Rabbis and other teachers, maybe, on how to instruct people in matters of observance in such a way that the recipient of their guidance understands observance as a path to increased holiness and doesn't mistake it for a burden? Is there advice for individuals on how to approach a mitzvah so that it can be appreciated, not merely fulfilled (or even just endured)?

Comment: The last paragraph seems to ask for something different than the rest of the question: "Are there guidelines for Rabbis and other teachers, maybe, on how to instruct people in matters of observance in such a way that the recipient of their guidance understands observance as a path to increased holiness and doesn't mistake it for a burden" this is different from asking if there are _mitzvot_ designed to protect one's love for God. Additionally, the last paragraph seems too broad.

Comment: @mevaqesh Yes, the last paragraph is different to the previous ones: if it were was asking exactly the same question as them, it would have been pointless my writing it. Since I don't know *at all* what might be the possible answers to my question, how do you imagine that I would be able to focus it? If *you* know which the superfluous branches are, it would be very helpful if you were to use the edit function.

Answer (score 3):

According to the "Duties of the Heart" love of God is a very advanced level. It requires lots of foundation work as explained in chapter 3 of the Gate of Love of God there. Here is an excerpt. You'll need to study the whole book to fully understand his words.

> What is the way to attaining love of G-d? I answer this question as
>   follows: This request is not possible for the seeker without many
>   prerequisites. When the prerequisites are fulfilled, there will emerge
>   from them the love of G-d. But one who has intent to it directly will
>   not reach it...
>
> ...When one will fulfill all of these and combine them with abstinence
>   from the pleasures and lusts of this world, and he understands the
>   greatness of the Creator, His might and exaltedness, reflects how
>   small is his own worth, how puny and lowly he is, and he comes to
>   realize the great benevolence of the Creator on him, and His great
>   kindness with him - then the love of G-d from the believer will come,
>   with a perfect heart and with genuine purity of soul, and a longing
>   for G-d that will be with exertion, zeal, and passion

http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=394#ch3

Comment: how does this answer he question?